# Why do the Sannoh players all have buzz cut hair?

Tags: slam-dunk

[Sannoh](http://slamdunk.wikia.com/wiki/Sannoh_Industry_Affiliated_High_School), the defending national champions, are a team of [buzz cut hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_cut). Here are their starters:

[image: Sannoh starters]

Even their substitute (Mikio) has the same haircut:

[image: Mikio]

This gives the team a very distinctive appearance and no doubt makes them look intimidating.

- Was it ever explained in the manga (or other media) why they all have this haircut?
- Were they based on some real-life team or players that had this haircut?

Comment: I guess it give a serious look. Like they're really sportsmen and train alot.

Comment: Sports teams have somewhat military parallels. The idea is that by making everyone wear a uniform (and get the same haircut) it helps group cohesion and improves team work. It helps reinforce the idea that no one is special; there is no "i" in team. Like with the army, you can check your individuality and uniqueness at the door; there's a job to be done. More importantly, it doesn't just make them *look* serious, it makes them *feel* serious.